# IsPostBack doesn't work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ispostback

I want that when the page is first loaded , the string str is initialized with the text "I am here". And when the page is updated by clicking on the button (btn_click) the value is the same that was initialized. But it does not work. In the console I reads:

First time I load the page: "I ​​am here"

1.When I click on the button: "empty"

2.And I think we should keep this value: "I am here". Please help.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string str = "empty";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                str = "I am here";
                Debug.Write("VALUE: " + str + "\r\n");
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.Write("VALUE: " + str + "\r\n");
            }
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something...
        }
}
```

Comment: Move the str initialization outside the IsPostBack loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual request to the server creates a new instance of the page... both the very first request (`IsPostBack==false`) and all subsequent requests (`IsPostBack==true`).

This means that your `str` variable is initialised with `"empty"` every time you request the page, but only ever set to `"I am here"` on the first load (i.e. the `IsPostBack==false`).  You need to store it somehow so that when the post-back occurs you still have it.

There are several ways, including using the `Session` object, but I would suggest using the `ViewState` like this...

```
string str = "empty";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    str = "I am here";
    ViewState["str"] = str;
    Debug.Write("VALUE: " + str + "\r\n");
  }
  else
  {
    str = (string)ViewState["str"];
    Debug.Write("VALUE: " + str + "\r\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome @Paul9999 - always good to try and remember that the instance of the page class is created each and every time - good luck with the rest of your project :-)